# matching two different ontologies

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

I have ontology A has Class (Product) and data properties (name, version, and date). Ontology B has Class (App) and data properties (name, version, and date). I would like to match class Product from ontology A with class App from ontology B based on the similarities between their data properties names, versions. What type of matching this is called and why?

Answer (score 3):

This type of matching is not possible by default, i.e without code or rules, because of the open world assumption. The open world assumption makes it such that, to a reasoner, there is no way to know that there are no *additional* properties on either class. Thus if you were to state that `name`, `version` and `date` from A is equivalent to `name`, `version` and `date` from B, a reasoner would *not* infer that `Product` from A is equivalent to `App` from B.

However, if you were to use some sort of ontology framework like Owl api or Apache Jena, you could write a bit of code that compares properties of the two classes and states that they are equivalent.

Comment: I understand, but I see Ontology Matching workshop, there are different papers talking about ontology matching techniques, which are confused me to classify my ontology matching under which category.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't quite understand by what you mean by categories of ontology matching so I cannot elaborate on my answer. Do you mean the semantics associated with the matching? Or if not, can you link me to the literature that is causing your confusion?

Comment: @Sultan The process of constructing a mapping between ontologies (e.g., asserting axioms like Kunal describes:  "name from A is the same as name from B") is called ontology mapping.  There are different strategies for doing this.  You could look for properties that have similar names (e.g., ontA:name and ontB:nameOf) have "name" in common.  You could look for properties that have similar values (e.g., x rdfs:label "Mount Monadnock" . x foaf:name "Mount Monadnock" suggests that rdfs:label and foaf:name may be related).  I don't know if these are principled enough to be considered different...

Comment: ...categories of ontology matching, but the point remains that people have developed lots of different techniques for generating mappings between ontologies.

Comment: @KunalKhaladkar here is the link for ontology matching techniques [link] (http://disi.unitn.it/~p2p/RelatedWork/Matching/Cerdeira-Ontology%20Matching-2015.pdf)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I agree with you about lots of different techniques for generating mappings. The question is, if the mapping done on level of similarities between names, versions and dates, what is the proper scientific name for that? 
In the provided link - Figure.7 shows the matching techniques classification. Extracted from the book ‘Ontology Matching’ (Euzenat & Shvaiko, 2013). I would like to know which technique should I use as a name for my question

Comment: @Sultan OK, I think that the scope of your question is pretty well defined then.  I think you won't find any universal naming conventions yet, but you might find some common ones.  You might look to things like "syntactic mapping" (e.g., putting the ontologies in the same formal representation (DAML, OIL, OWL, RDFS, etc.), "lexical mapping" where you say that properties/classes with the same names are consider similar, "semantic mappings" based on axioms, "statistical mappings" based on instance data, etc.  You might get more useful answers on answers.semanticweb.com, too.